# Empty validatedBy in @Constraint

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, bean-validation

I noticed that all built-in constraints have an empty value for the `validatedBy` parameter in `@Constraint`. i.e. `@Constraint(validatedBy = {})`

First, why are they allowed to have an empty value for `validatedBy`? I thought you can leave it blank only for constraint composition that does not need addtional validation?

Also, note that the Hibernate Validator can still find a validator implementation class for each built-in constraint, despite the `validatedBy` is empty, but if I leave the validatedBy blank for my constraint, my custom validator never gets picked up. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Another reason why I think this API is flawed

Comment: just for completeness, this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544588/hibernate-validator-to-validate-constraints-if-constraintvalidated-by

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those built-in are treated in special implementation-specific way and their validators are configured programmatically.

For Hibernate Validator it's done in [`ConstraintHelper.java`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/hibernate-validator/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/metadata/ConstraintHelper.java). I think you can't achieve the same for your custom constraints.

Comment: Thanks, so I can't leave the validatedBy for my constraint blank and expect Hibernate Validator to pick up my custom validator?

Comment: No, you must specify your custom validator in the annotation for Hibernate to find it.

Comment: Nowadays you can decouple the constraint definition (interface) and the validator itself, leaving the validatedBy empty, and making Hibernate to locate the validator using for example the ServiceLoader: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_code_serviceloader_code

Answer (score 5):

Maybe have a look at this answer:

[How to avoid cross dependency between layers because of @Constraint validatedBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720726/how-to-avoid-cross-dependency-between-layers-because-of-constraint-validatedby)

And those two links:

Adding constraints programmatically:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#section-programmatic-api

Adding constraints per xml:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there are [several methods](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-definition-contribution) to decouple the interface with the constraint definition and the validator, so you can have them in different layers and leave the *validatedBy* attribute empty. One of the simplest is using [Hibernate ServiceLoader](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_code_serviceloader_code) adding the validator classes in a `/META-INF/services/javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` file in resources folder (changed to `jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator` with Hibernate 7).