# Is it possible to use an interface as a validatedBy

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I want to split a declaration and implementation of my validator very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720726/how-to-avoid-cross-dependency-between-layers-because-of-constraint-validatedby/18352754) in my Spring boot environment. It looks like I somehow made it almost working. I see that my validator is actually called by Spring validation, but after a validation is executed, Hibernate throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.UniqueUsernameValidator.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3427) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2165) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:41) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.run(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.getInstance(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:28) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.newInstance(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:84) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.createAndInitializeValidator(AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:136) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:54) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedAnnotatedObjectForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:629) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:590) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:880) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:283) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:104) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at test.AuthenticationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b10b56.signUp(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

It's because `UniqueUsernameValidator` is an interface (as intended).

I've configured Spring like this (solution from  [this answert to some differenet question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39907824/658801)):

```
  @Bean
  public Validator validator() {
    SpringConstraintValidatorFactoryEx scvf =
        new SpringConstraintValidatorFactoryEx(wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setConstraintValidatorFactory(scvf);
    validator.setApplicationContext(wac);
    validator.afterPropertiesSet();
    return validator;
  }
```

My custom validator:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SpringConstraintValidatorFactoryEx implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {

  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  public SpringConstraintValidatorFactoryEx(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    super();
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
  }

  public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
    T bean = null;

    try {
      log.info("Trying to find a validator bean of class " + key.getSimpleName());
      bean = (T) this.beanFactory.getBean(key);
    } catch (BeansException exc) {
      log.info(
          "Failed to find a bean of class {}, message {}", key.getSimpleName(), exc.getMessage());
    }

    if (bean == null) {
      try {
        log.info("Creating a new validator bean of class " + key.getSimpleName());
        bean = this.beanFactory.createBean(key);
      } catch (BeansException exc) {
        log.info("Failed to create a validator of class " + key.getSimpleName());
      }
    }

    if (bean == null) {
      log.warn("Failed to get validator of class " + key.getSimpleName());
    }

    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {}
}
```

So it tries to find a Spring bean by a validator name. So I have an implementation of my validator:

```
@Component
public class UniqueUsernameValidatorImpl implements UniqueUsernameValidator {
  @Autowired private UserCredentialsRepository repository;

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return repository.findByUsername(value).isEmpty();
  }
}
```

A validator interface:

```
public interface UniqueUsernameValidator extends ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

}
```

A constraint annotation:

```
@Target({
  ElementType.METHOD,
  ElementType.FIELD,
  ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
  ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
  ElementType.PARAMETER,
  ElementType.TYPE_USE
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(UniqueUsername.List.class)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {UniqueUsernameValidator.class})
public @interface UniqueUsername {
  String message() default "username must be unique";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  @Target({
    ElementType.METHOD,
    ElementType.FIELD,
    ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
    ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
    ElementType.PARAMETER,
    ElementType.TYPE_USE
  })
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Documented
  @interface List {
    UniqueUsername[] value();
  }
}
```

It looks like Spring validation somehow manage to use my implementation of a validator, but then a Hibernate fails to instantiate a validator(?). I don't fully understand why there are 2 different initializations of validation mechanisms.

Is there a way to "register" or "inform" Hibernate validation to use my implementation of my custom validation annotation?

Comment: Would you please put them here? log for your own classes.

Comment: I think in this portion of code Spring failed to `getBean` and throws an exception right? 
`try {
      log.info("Trying to find a validator bean of class " + key.getSimpleName());
      bean = (T) this.beanFactory.getBean(key);
    } catch (BeansException exc) {
      log.info(
          "Failed to find a bean of class {}, message {}", key.getSimpleName(), exc.getMessage());
    } `

Comment: @tashkhisi For nonexisting beans - yes. But for the one I'm interested in - imlementation of `UsernameUniqueValidator` it works just fine. Spring finds this bean and executes the validation code. The problem is that later, hibernate fails to instantiate an interface (obviously)

Comment: What happen when you set this property? `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Validator is using the default impl of `ConstraintValidatorFactory` (see `ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl` in your stacktrace) so that means your custom one is not taken into account somehow.

It's failing in the method validation, maybe you need to provide an `ExecutableValidator` bean?

(Hibernate Validator lead here, I don't know exactly how Spring wired things).