# How do i inject ConstrainValidator?

Tags: java, spring, validation, constraints, hibernate-validator

Imagine i have an annotation *A*

```
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {Validator.class})
public @interface A {

   String value() default "";

   String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.form.customization.message}";

   Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

that has a Constraint *Validator* which is **not** an implementation of *ConstraintValidator* rather an extension of one

```
public interface Validator extends ConstraintValidator<A, Entity> {
}
```

And then some implementation of Validator. Is there any way i can make it work with Spring, dependency injection and all that good stuff? Thank you

Comment: Does `@Component` on the implementation of `Validator` not work?

Comment: @Prashant wouldn't that be a perfect world....

Comment: Hahaha, can you please provide more information. With the information provided, this would be closest guess I could make.

Comment: validatedBy should point to a concrete class, not an interface. But you can assign multiple validators... like `@Constraint(validatedBy = {AValidator.class, BValidator})`

Comment: @DirkDeyne i don't really get how multiple validators will help in my situation) There has to be a way through some configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okkkkkkkkkkkkk, it's actually possible.

Turns out this question is kind of a copy of [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720726/how-to-avoid-cross-dependency-between-layers-because-of-constraint-validatedby#comment113843132_18352754). The only thing is it won't work just yet. Here's the final piece of code you have to add to your configuration.

```
    @Bean
    Validator validatorFactory() {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                .configure()
                .constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactoryEx())
                .buildValidatorFactory();

        return validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }
```

It's from Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=7.0#_code_constraintvalidatorfactory_code) in case someone is wondering