# Multiple validation options in Annotation

Tags: annotations, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

My question is a branch of of [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512826/empty-validatedby-in-constraint)

I have a Annotation (say phone annotation) that I want to validate. I can use @phone validator to check if a phone object is valid or not. I want to also be able to place this validator on a contact information object that contains a phone. Is there a way to use multiple validators for one annotation so I can use @phone for my phone object and my contact information object?
Would something like 
`@Constraint(validatedBy = {PhoneIsValid.class, PhoneIsValid2.class})` 
work? (The idea being one Validator handles the phone object and the other handles the contact information object.)

Comment: Do you mean that BOTH the validators must return true for the value to be valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple validators for the same annotation type.
As you mentioned, you have define all of them in the `@Constraint` annotation.

Annotaion:

```
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ValidPhonePhoneValidator.class, ValidPhoneContactValidator.class })
public @interface ValidPhone {

  String message() default "";
  Class<?>[] groups() default { };
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator1:

```
public class ValidPhonePhoneValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPhone, Phone> { ... }
```

Validator2:

```
public class ValidPhoneContactValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPhone, Contact> { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and it works for me. The annotations go to the proper class for validation.

Comment: ConstraintValidator<A extends Annotation, T>. How are object Phone and Contact of type Annotation?

Comment: @AdiV you’re right. The validator definitions were wrong. I updated them.

Comment: That does not work for me; I get this error:
HV000150: The constraint NirValidator defines multiple validators for the type NirResource:  NirCalculCleConstraint,  NirBrutLongueurConstraint. Only one is allowed.