# Hibernate validator to validate constraints if @Constraint(validated by = {})

Tags: java, spring-mvc, constraints, hibernate-validator

I have a Spring webapplication that uses hibernate validator for validation. I have constraint annotations that are located in a different project. I need to have validators for these constraints in my  spring project because I need some services to perform validation. So the situation is: I cannot place my constraint validators in @Constraint(validatedBy = MyConstraintValidator.class) because the validator is in a different project, I cannot add a dependency because that would create a cyclic dependency and it is just not the way we want it.
I noticed that javax.constraints don't have validators specified, it's just @Constraint(validatedBy= {}).
But hibernate validator still knows how to validate them.
Is there a way to tell my hibernate validator how to validate my constraints without specifying constaint-validators in my constraints?

I hope be able to validate this constraint:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface OneOf {

    String message() default "{OneOf}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `javax.validation.constraints` leaves the validators to the implementation. Hibernate provides validators to these constraints, and registers them when bootstrapping.

You can set the validators via XML without using `@Constraint(validatedBy = { })`. However, this is usually used to add to/replace the provided validators with your own. I'm not sure how it will help you since you still need to reference the constraint validator.

Example of using XML constraint definition:

```
<constraint-definition annotation="org.mycompany.CheckCase">
    <validated-by include-existing-validators="false">
        <value>org.mycompany.CheckCaseValidator</value>
    </validated-by>
</constraint-definition>
```

See: [Configuring via XML](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-xml-configuration)

The upcoming 5.2 release provides more ways such as using a service loader or implementing `ConstraintDefinitionContributor`. See: [Providing constraint definitions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-definition-contribution)

Comment: The first Alpha of 5.2 is out now, it also provides support for custom `ConstraintDefinitionContributor`s.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this although couldn't try it.. for some reason validation.xml gives parse exception.. and I have to use 4.3 version